# Recyclerview item layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Is there any way to change `recyclerview` item's layout dynamically f.e. by pressing on the item?
I thought maybe it would work if we simply remove the item and instantly create another one so onCreateViewHolder is called?

Comment: The thing is the old layout would be reloaded everytime you scroll away and back to that item unless you put a condition im the getview to check for changed layouts

Comment: you can change the recyclerview's item layout dynamically, but it would be better if you can elaborate more your requirement alongwith required code so that I can answer specific to yuor requirement.

Comment: kindly check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741895/list-view-item-selected-background-changed-it-changes-other-item-also/    .... although it uses ListView the internal change which you are looking for is there