# Changing listviewitem background color in adapter gives unexpected results

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, listview-adapter

I am populating a ListView from an ArrayList and in the getView() method of the adapter I am trying to set the background color of a specific item based on a property of the User that it is displaying.

The code I pasted below gives me unexpected results on scrolling the list view.
When I enter the application the first items displayed are colored properly, but as I scroll the list it colors some items green, despite the fact that the tested property is 0.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  User user = getItem(position);

  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
  }

  if (user.newStatus > 0) convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

  //some other stuff happens here

  return convertView;
}
```

In case I didn't explain well, even though `user.newStatus` is 0, SOME ListViewItems get colored green regardless.

Comment: do if else if (user.newStatus > 0){
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }else{
  
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

Comment: Oh my god thank you. It was so obvious. I need to take a break :)
EDIT: Actually it wasn't that obvious since it is not very logical. Does this have something to do with the views being reused? Since it should be white by default.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741895/list-view-item-selected-background-changed-it-changes-other-item-also/34742289#34742289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of [ListView's recycling mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/4224337).

Adding the `else` case, will fix it:

```
if (user.newStatus > 0) {
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(yourDefaultColor);
}
```